# How to Represent a View in TypeOrm?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I need to represent DB views as Entities in typeOrm to apply queries on these views, Is there a way to make that ?

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1024

View entity implemented and will be released in 0.2.17. Here is the [docs](https://typeorm.io/#/view-entities).